# Powershell: Take items from an array and assign variables to them

Tags: arrays, string, object, powershell

I'm trying to extract the GUIDS from this list.

Get-WMIObject WIN32_Product | ? {$_.IdentifyingNumber -like "*26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F8321*FF*"} | Format-List IdentifyingNumber

is it possible to convert each item into a string and possibly assign them to variables?

Here's what I was trying, but it's not working. but maybe this will show the logic i am trying:

$A = Get-WMIObject WIN32_Product | ? {$_.IdentifyingNumber -like "*26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F8321*FF*"} | Format-List IdentifyingNumber

$GUIDList = ForEach-Object{$A.ToString()}

$GUIDList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format-list is, as the name suggests, for display formatting purposes.

Based on your usage, I suppose you can use Select-Object instead:

```
| Select-Object IdentifyingNumber
```

After that you will have an array of objects with property IdentifyingNumbers.

If you just want array /list of strings ( assuming the property is string ) you could do:

```
| Select-Object -expand IdentifyingNumber
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't realize it was that easy! Thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another useful option that uses a WQL filter and uses the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet to extract the identifiers:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "IdentifyingNumber LIKE "%26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F8321%FF%"} | 
Foreach-Object {$_.IdentifyingNumber}
```